# Running Powershell script within Powershell 'silently'

Tags: powershell

My setup:

One Powershell script with a menu. Upon selecting a a menu item, a specific Powershell script is run assigned to that menu item.
I'm attempting to make this second Powershell script run silently as in - nothing is shown in the main Powershell script.

Bonus:
The full setup I'm looking at is:

- User runs Powershell script
- User selects a menu item (this executes another Powershell script)
- The information in the other Powershell script is not shown to the user
- After the second Powershell script has been executed, the user is shown a line of text such as: "Script has been run successfully"

What I've tried:
Adding the following code to each secondary script

```
$t = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindow(int handle, int state);'
add-type -name win -member $t -namespace native
[native.win]::ShowWindow(([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess() | Get-Process).MainWindowHandle, 0)
```

Unfortunately this closes the main Powershell window which isn't what I desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by appending

```
| out-null
```

at the end of each line of code in the secondary scripts.

Answer (score 2):

You could run the secondary command as a background-job and wait for it to finish. That way no output is shown in the shell

```
Start-Job -FilePath YourSecondaryScript.ps1 | Wait-Job
```

if you need, you can still analyze the job result (the script output)